# Alarm Manager is not working in Xiaomi phones

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have tried most of the solution provided on StackOverflow and google about `AlarmManager` for Marshmallow OS. But I didn;t get the solution.

Code:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, UpdateTables.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();

        //midnight
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

if (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() > alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis()) {
            Log.i("Current time ", Constants.getDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
            alarmStartTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

 alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmStartTime.getTimeInMills(), pendingIntent);
```

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class UpdateTables extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

}
}
```

When I am closing the app then the set alarm is removed from the scheduled alarm list:

```
 ./adb shell dumpsys alarm
```

So I have created the service that calls `AlarmManager` again `onTaskRemoved()` from recent apps:

```
public class myService extends Service {


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {

        setTheTimeToUpdateTables(getApplicationContext());
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

}
```

Solution Tried:

1. Add the app to the autostart list.
2. Remove the app from battery saver list.
3. Use the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` instead of `BroadCastReciever`.

Comment: could you solve it?

Comment: try this: https://medium.com/mindorks/enable-background-services-in-chinese-roms-32e73dfba1a6